# How to iterate over multiple values from socket

Tags: javascript, sockets, reactjs, websocket

I am trying to get data from a socket for multiple chat rooms. I have been able to log the data (using `event.data`) but I am having trouble representing the data in the return.

I tried using two maps (one to get the chat room name, one to get a list of it's messages). How is this achieved?

```
const MessageSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/chat');

class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    MessageSocket.addEventListener('message', event => {
      console.log('one at a time', event.data)
      this.setState(prev => { 
        return {
          data: { ...prev.data, ...event.data }
        }
      });
      const values = Object.values(JSON.parse(event.data))
      console.log(values)
    });
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          The room title is: {values.map(e => <h2>{values}</h2>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

## The data (it console.logs each one individually)

```
{
  "Room 1": [{
    "pk": 1,
    "message": "Hi",
    "handle": "Foo",
  }, {
    "pk": 2,
    "message": "Hello",
    "handle": "Bar",
  }]
}
```

## Another console log entry

```
{
  "Room 2": [{
    "pk": 1,
    "message": "See ya",
    "handle": "Bob",
  }, {
    "pk": 2,
    "message": "Laters",
    "handle": "Pete",
  }]
}
```

Comment: Your render function has no variable `values` in its scope. Also, your map function is not mapping anything, you are merely trying to output `values` on each iteration.

Comment: So please provide an example of how to use it

Answer (score 0):

`const values = …` assigns a local variable. You can't refer to it in `render()` just like that. In order to use anything from `componentWillMount()` in `render()`, you have to pass it into `setState({foo: something})` and access it via `this.state.foo`.

Comment: But I am using this.SetState within the componentWillMount. `this.setState(prev => { return { data: { ...prev.data, ...event.data } }`. When I trying using that data via `this.state.data` I get the error `Cannot read property 'data' of null`